# spring SPEL add hard coded string to expression

Tags: spring, spring-el

We want to append a hard coded string to the evaluated expression. Is that possible using SPEL?

Example:

I have an Employee class which has a collection of String. `List<String> codes;`

I am able to get this collection using the below expression .

```
expression = expressionParser.parseExpression("codes");
List<String> evaluatedCodes = (List<String>) expression.getValue(evaluationContext);
System.out.println(" evaluatedCodes " + evaluatedCodes);
```

I want to prefix the output with a string .

```
expression = expressionParser.parseExpression("'PREFIX' + codes");
List<String> evaluatedCodes = (List<String>) expression.getValue(evaluationContext);
System.out.println(" evaluatedCodes " + evaluatedCodes);
```

This does not work. Is there any way I can prefix the output with a hard coded string ?

I get the below exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at com.muhad.spel.ExampleConfigurationTests.testSPEL(ExampleConfigurationTests.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)

Thanks

Lives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please expand on

> it does not work.

I just tested it and it works fine for me...

```
public class Foo {

    public List<String> getCodes() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"foo", "bar"});
    }
}

...
    Expression e = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("'foo' + codes");
    Object value = e.getValue(evalCtx, new Foo());
    System.out.println(value);
```

produces `foofoo,bar`

and

```
    Expression e = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("'foo' + codes.toString()");
```

produces `foo[foo, bar]`

The difference being because in the first case the list is converted to a string by the conversion service rather than a simple `toString()`.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I missed that you want a list of modified values returned; the above solutions produce strings.

To prefix each value, you need to use [Collection Projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-projection)...

```
Expression e = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("codes.!['foo' + #this]");
```

Comment: updated the exception trace. I tried both with and without toString . After the string concatenation , wont the evaluated output still be a List<string> ?

Comment: I want the final output to be foofoo , foobar in your example . Basicaly "foo" should be prefixed to each string in the collection

Comment: Thanks . That worked .I have used projection but could not get this expression . Now I understood how projection is working.